# check for garbage value Objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to get the range of a particular substring using rangeOfString method of the NSString instance.. the problem is it sometimes returns garbage value..

Is there a way i could do a comparison for the garbage value and skip the next steps if the range sent is garbage..

thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific about 'garbage value'?

Comment: Are you sure it is garbage? Compare the location of the range to NSNotFound.

Comment: yeah.. it is garbage.. if u log the value for range.position.. u will see it too be huge value..

Comment: technically that's not "garbage."  Garbage would imply that you read the wrong location in memory, and got a series of 0 and 1's that has no relevance.  The value instead is `NSNotFound` which, while a very large value, is an OS constant and very meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range is not found, you'll get a `NSRange` with `{NSNotFound, 0}`.  You can find this [here in the documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a)

This is the test you'll want:

```
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@"doobleydoo"];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) return;
```